# Can PreparedStatementSetter will be used for Delete query in Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, prepared-statement, sql-delete

I am using Spring 3.1.2,am using PreparedStatementSetter for Select, update and insert, but how can I use for Delete query?

Comment: the same way u use it for insert and update. Use executeUpdate method to run the delete query.

Answer (score 1):

jdbcTemplate.update() can be used for delete's

e.g.

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
jdbcTemplate.update("delete from my_table where value=? ", new PreparedStatementSetter() {
  public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
    ps.setLong(1, 2L);//or setString or whatever
  }
});
```

you can also execute a delete without the PreparedStatementSetter as shown here:  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/UseJdbcTemplateToExecuteDeleteStatementWithParameter.htm

Comment: Did you compare both performance? I mean between a way in the link and prepered statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PreparedStatement` for deletion like this

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = yourDBConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, 1001);

// execute delete SQL stetement
ps.executeUpdate();
```